# Why are [questions] and [asking-questions] on meta?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request, retag-request, meta

If I want to scan the list of titles of all topics on meta about 'questions', then I need to do that twice (once for each tag, [questions](/questions/tagged/questions) and [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions)).

Could one of them be synonymized or merged with the other (I don't know which)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about this one.  After comparing the questions, I can see some differences:

- Questions tagged as [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) mostly involve asking about whether or not a certain question can be asked here.
- Questions tagged as [questions](/questions/tagged/questions) involve things such as feature requests or anything else about existing questions (which are also not about [specific-questions](/questions/tagged/specific-questions)).

In this case, it seems that synonymizing or merging them would not make sense.  Plus, MSO has these two tags separate, and the mechanics of these tags should still apply to per-site metas.

Comment: In that case I think that [Does my code example need to be compilable/runnable?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/427/does-my-code-example-need-to-be-compilable-runnable) should be asking-questions, not questions. Ditto http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/661/questions-that-ask-for-you-to-e-mail-them-to-get-the-code and http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213/where-do-high-level-architecture-and-design-questions-go and http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134/reviews-of-code-not-stored-here

Comment: @ChrisW: I do agree that those should be retagged (and it looks like the [faq] one escaped me at first).

Comment: All the [questions] are boring now (except the [best-of] [fun] questions). If I want to know site-specific policy about asking questions (e.g. what's on-topic) I can just read [asking-questions].

Comment: Could you edit both tag wikis to point out the difference?

Comment: @200_success: Yes I could.